# Symfony2 - get entity object in PRE_SUBMIT event

Tags: symfony, events, entity, listener

I have a form and `PRE_SUBMIT` event added.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));
```

Now when I dump form data in the event I get an array and not an object.

```
public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    /** @var Offer $offer */
    $offer = $event->getData();

    var_dump($offer);
    die;
}
```

Here in the event I would like to check the state field of entity which is not in the form and depending on state add some constraints to certain fields.

The array does not contain `id` of an entity...

P.S. I would use `SUBMIT` to get an entity object, but in this case `SUBMIT` event is too late to add the constraints.

Comment: the $event->getData() is the request data, and $form->getData() is the entity, but it's the original entity not the submitted.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#component-form-event-table for more info

Comment: This is what I need since state does not change when submitting! Please post it as answer and I will mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the $event->getData() is the request data, and $form->getData() is the entity, but it's the original entity not the submitted.
see http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#component-form-event-table for more info